# Variables doesn't null after step of loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to count chars of data in columns, so I'm using `for` loop to do it.
Here is an example of my code:

```
Sub CharCount()
    Dim Counter As Long

    For Counter = 1 To 257 Step 1
        Dim SumA As Variant
        Dim SumB As Variant
        Dim SumC As Variant
        SumA = 0
        SumB = 0
        SumC = 0
        Dim j As Long
        For j = Counter To Counter * 257 Step 1
            SumA = SumA + Len(Cells(j, 1))
            SumB = SumB + Len(Cells(j, 2))
            SumC = SumC + Len(Cells(j, 3))
        Next j
        Range("E" & Counter) = SumA
        Range("F" & Counter) = SumB
        Range("G" & Counter) = SumC
        SumA = Null
        SumB = Null
        SumC = Null
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

As you can see, I'm trying to `Null` variables for sum, but it doesn't seem to work and after each step of loop these variables just stack values of previous steps. How can I null variables?

I already tried these versions of code:

1:

```
Sub CharCount()
    Dim Counter As Long

    For Counter = 1 To 257 Step 1
        SumA = 0
        SumB = 0
        SumC = 0
        Dim j As Long
        For j = Counter To Counter * 257 Step 1
            SumA = SumA + Len(Cells(j, 1))
            SumB = SumB + Len(Cells(j, 2))
            SumC = SumC + Len(Cells(j, 3))
        Next j
        Range("E" & Counter) = SumA
        Range("F" & Counter) = SumB
        Range("G" & Counter) = SumC
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

2:

```
Sub CharCount()
    Dim Counter As Long

    For Counter = 1 To 257 Step 1
        SumA = 0
        SumB = 0
        SumC = 0
        Dim j As Long
        For j = Counter To Counter * 257 Step 1
            SumA = SumA + Len(Cells(j, 1))
            SumB = SumB + Len(Cells(j, 2))
            SumC = SumC + Len(Cells(j, 3))
        Next j
        Range("E" & Counter) = SumA
        Range("F" & Counter) = SumB
        Range("G" & Counter) = SumC
        SumA = 0
        SumB = 0
        SumC = 0
    Next Counter
End Sub`
```

First and second versions doesn't work for me.

UPD. It was just my fault in algorithm. After debugging I noticed that all variables successfully nulled after step of loop.

Comment: SumA=0 instead of Null

Comment: You're setting them to `Null` outside of the `j` loop.  This code appears to correctly `Null` the variables within the `Counter` loop.  Note that you can't add to a null value, i.e., `SumA = Null + 1` will yield a `Null` result. You probably should be assigning these values as `0` rather than `Null`.

Comment: Wouldn't the loop set them to 0 at the start of each iteration anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

..............use **0** rather than **Null**

Comment: I tried this and this not working for me. Varieables continue to stack. No matter how many times I try to 0 or `Null` them.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things:

1. You should not dimension your variables within the `For` loop. Move those out of the loop below the first one.
2. If `SumA`, `SumB`, and `SumC` are always integers, you should dimension them as `Long` or `Integer` instead of variant.
3. You're resetting each of these variables to 0 at the start of the loop, so there is no need for the `SumA = Null`, `SumB = Null`, and `SumC = Null` lines.

Comment: I already tried these solutions, but `SumA`, `SubB` and `SumC` just stack sum of each step of loop. At the beggining I just assign them to 0, like `SumA = 0` without dimension, then I tried this after assign values of sum to cells. Then I tried to `Null` them. It just doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "stack"? I have a feeling you are getting the error because they are dimensioned as `Variant` instead of `Long`.

Comment: I edited my question with two versions that I already tried. I'll try to move dimensions out of the loop and dimension them as `Integer`

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you mean by "stack." Does it continue to add the numbers or does it put one number at the end of the previous number?

Comment: It's ok, I just debug my code and there is my fault in algorithm. All variables are successfully null